# Drawing coordinate system with tikz and changing offset, spacing etc

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, tkz-collection

I am trying to draw a coordinate system with tikz on top of a picture. I am trying to re-recreate the coordinate system in the attached figure as a test, but I have a few problems

1. How do I change the offset of the coordinate system so it is right at the south-west corner of the figure?
2. How do I change the spacing of the x- and y-axis so that they run from a min-value to a max-value with a step I decide?

My code is the following so far. This draws the coordinate system, but now I have to move it to the corner and change the spacing and max/min values:

```
\documentclass[border=30pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}

\begin{document}  

\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[anchor=south west,inner sep=0] at (0,0) {\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{test.jpg}};

       \tkzInit[xmax=8,ymax=1,xmin=0,ymin=0]
       \tkzAxeXY
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

---

[image]

Comment: You can check [this question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/9559/9335).

Comment: Why don't you use pgfplots?

Comment: @EnricoMariaDeAngelis I am very interested to see an example of how to do it with pgfplots

Comment: @BillyJean, I added my answer. Hope it's good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be more readable and working:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.13}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[xmin=0,xmax=7,ymin=0,ymax=7,
             xtick={0,1.333,...,7},
             ytick={0,1,...,7},
             view={0}{90}]
\addplot3[surf,shader=interp]
coordinates {
      (0,0,0) (7,0,0)

      (0,7,1) (7,7,1)
};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, this is much more readable. Is is possible to shift the position of the coordinate system? Right now I am plotting the axes on top of a figure I load in externally using ` \node [inner sep=0pt] (c) {\includegraphics[scale=1]{urxul.jpg}};`, and I need to move the coordinate system to the corner of this picture

Comment: Maybe I don't understand what you mean by _position of the coordinate system_. If you're talking about the origin of the CS, then you can just set negative `xmin` and `ymin` in order to have the origin in the inner part of the `axis`. You could add a hand sketch of what you want to your question.

Comment: Thanks, that worked. A final question, I hope this is alright: Is it possible to scale the x- and y-axis independently? So I can set their length manually. Right now I am using `width=4cm`, but this changes both axes

Comment: Check [this](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/39093/how-do-i-set-the-aspect-ratio-of-2d-flattened-3d-surface-plot)

Comment: Thanks, you really pushed me forward. I ended up using your solution, it is IMO much simpler to grasp

Answer (score 4):

You can just draw over the image in the way the links you've been directed to illustrate. A few loops save typing, but that's all.

```
\documentclass[border=10pt,multi,tikz]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node [inner sep=0pt] (c) {\includegraphics[scale=3]{changeable}};
  \begin{scope}[shift=(c.south west), x=(c.south east), y=(c.north west)]
    \coordinate (x0) at (1,0);
    \path (0,0) \foreach \i in {1,...,8} { ++({1/8.1},0) node (x\i) [below, font=\scriptsize] {\i 0} edge [thin] +(0,2.5pt)};
    \path (0,1) coordinate (y0) \foreach \i in {1,...,8} { ++(0,-{1/8.1}) node (y\i) [left, font=\scriptsize] {\i 0} edge [thin] +(2.5pt,0)};
    \foreach \i in {1,...,8} \draw [thin] (y0 -| x\i) edge [gray!50, thin] +(0,-2.5pt) (x0 |- y\i) -- +(-2.5pt,0);
  \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: fake shading with looping tick marks]